# Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to make an applicatin using typescript with angularjs. but I am getting this error

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

app.ts is

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import IModule  = ng.IModule;

export class App{
    public static bootstrap():void{

    const app : IModule = angular.module('app',).component('sachin',{
        template:'<div>sdafdsfa</div>',
        controller:[function(){

        }],
        controllerAs:'vm'
    })

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"], {
        "strictDi": true,
    });
}
```

}

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" >

<head>
    <title>My AngularJS App with ts</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <sachin></sachin>
    <script src="vendors.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add
angular.js file in your html code